# SQL Server 2008 Instance connection issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My problem is the following:

I installes SQL Server 2008 R2 on my Windows Server 2008. I tried it by using default instance name (MSSQLSERVER) and named instance. The Installation was successful without an error. The problem is now:

When I try to connect to my SQL Server with the Management Studio it can't connect to this instance when I write "SERVER1\MSSQLSERVER" as serveraddress. When I write "SERVER1" only in the serveradress field it works.

Note: I always try to connect as SA. The password is right. Dont know if that matters...

But I have to be able to connect to "SERVER1\MSSQLSERVER" because I always get errors when I want to connect to a server without instance by C#.

Can someone tell me where I am mistaking?

EDIT:

The C# code looks like this:

```
sqlConnection = "data source=(local);persist security info=True;User ID=sa;Password=12345;initial catalog=BBKat"

SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection( sqlConnection );

SqlCommand    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand( sqlCmdString, sqlCon );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a single `(local)` in the server name. and the same in C# web config connectionString as `Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=YOUR_DB;Integrated Security=True`

**EDIT**

Change the connection string as:

```
data source=(local);Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=12345;initial catalog=BBKat
```

Comment: It's the same like like "SERVER1": it works in management studio but not in C#... :(

Comment: Can you tell me how you are using that in c#..?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not mistaken at all. You do not write the default instance name while connecting. You can create aliases though as mentioned above.